# Conditionally color background of PopupMenu

Tags: dynamic, format

I am designing a student workbook and I would like to put a PopupMenu alongside a question that will display all choices with standard gray or white background.  However, after they make selection I would like the background to dynamically or conditionally change to either green, yellow, or red based upon the answer to show level of correctness after they make choice.  I borrowed some code and have this so far:

```
PopupMenu[Dynamic[x], {"Tracking", "Fuzzy"}, Background -> Green, 
 Alignment -> {Center}, MenuStyle -> {Directive[Red, 12, Bold]}]
```

For example, if selection is "Tracking" then make background Green, if "Fuzzy" make red.

I would also like to experiment with displaying the menu choices text in different colors for purpose of self assessment on a topic or question.

Example: make "Tracking" Blue text and "Fuzzy" gray text within the menu.

Any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the background colour `Dynamic` as well and rewrite the `PopupMenu` to change the colour based on the value of `x`:

```
DynamicModule[{
  x = "Tracking"
  },
 PopupMenu[
  Dynamic[x]
  ,
  {"Tracking", "Fuzzy"},
  Background -> Dynamic[
    Which[
     x === "Tracking",
     Green,
     True,
     Lighter[Red]
     ]
    ],
  Alignment -> {Center}, MenuStyle -> {Directive[Red, 12, Bold]}
  ]
 ]
```

You can list other colours in the `Which` if you have more options, or you can make a lookup table with colours. Other appearance options can be made dynamic in much the same way.